# How to copy a column based on header from one workbook to another in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub copycolumns()

Dim y As Workbook
Dim x As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\hshabbir\Desktop\testing.xlsx")
Set sh = x.Sheets("Sheet2")

Set y = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = y.Sheets("Sheet1")
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

Dim i As Integer, searchedcolumn As Integer, searchheader As Object

For i = 1 To 8    
    Set searchheader = ws.Cells(1, i)    
    searchedcolumn = 0

    On Error Resume Next
    searchedcolumn = sh.Rows(1).Find(what:=searchheader.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    On Error GoTo 0

    If searchedcolumn <> 0 Then
        ws.Columns(searchedcolumn).Copy Destination:=searchheader     
    End If
Next i

x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: It is not copying data

Comment: Aren't you copying a column (`ws.Columns(searchedcolumn).Copy`) into a cell? (`Set searchheader = ws.Cells(1, i)`) And if you are not dealing the errors nothing happens I supose.

Answer (score 0):

When i use following programme withen work book, it works fine and copies the date from one sheets to another.
Sub copycolumns1()

Dim i As Integer, searchedcolumn As Integer, searchheader As Object

Set searchheader = Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1)

searchedcolumn = 0
On Error Resume Next
 searchedcolumn = Sheets(1).Rows(1).Find(what:=searchheader.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Column
 On Error GoTo 0

If searchedcolumn <> 0 Then
  Sheets(1).Columns(searchedcolumn).Copy Destination:=searchheader
 End If

End Sub

but  i am not getting it worked for moving from one workbook to another workbook